# Maximum allowed number of Push Notification that Apple allows

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

referring to Apple documentation regards Push Notification, i couldn't find anything regards the Maximum allowed number of push Notification.
This unlike Google Android where they mentioned the Maximum allowed, which could be exceeded with special permission from google.

by Maximum here I mean the Maximum allowed in one session and also in an hour for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not fixed from apple side. As it receive APNS request it serves them in a sequence. But it depends on your server capacity how much it can tolerate depending on its bandwidth. i have send around 50,000 APNS messages at a time it tooks around 15-30 minutes to process them on my server. And i have done the same for 3-4 times a day just for testing and i was able to send notifications. There server is strong enough to respond to these APNS